# This is ugly and there has to be a better way to write it in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, traversal

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('[name=reply_to_id]');
```

Thats just stupid looking, but its the best way i can think of writing it. I tried `parentsUntil('li')` but that didnt work at all and i also tried `parents('li')` and `closest('li')`. Isnt there something in jQuery with the equivalent of:

```
$(this).firstParentThatMatchesThis('li').find('[name=reply_to_id]');
```

If not i think ill try submitting it to the jQuery core...

Here is my HTML (long so i put it on pastebin): http://pastebin.com/FypJ9WGe

Working on getting JSFiddle in there...

Comment: Your HTML would be nice to see.

Comment: `closest` should do exactly what you want here. You'll need to post some markup too.

Comment: Post you example on http://jsfiddle.net/ and send as the link...

Comment: @why do you want to reach parent which is so far??? any reason..

Comment: why not have a id on the parent <ul>?

Comment: I do have an ID on the parent UL but each LI has a different comment form that's hidden attrs need to be updated on my side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(this).parents("li").eq(0).find('[name=reply_to_id]');
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/FvzT9/

But, `closest` should work as well:

```
$(this).closest("li").find('[name=reply_to_id]');
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/FvzT9/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).closest('li').find('[name=reply_to_id]');
```